# IOS, Swift: creating a split screen with 2 views, with animation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm an absolute IOS newbie studying Swift.

I'm trying to create an app with a calendar UI control on top (already got that working), and a listview on the bottom.

Exactly like the picture on the bottom (and I apologise for the huge pic).

Now, like the calendar app, the screen will only show the calendar control, but if you click a button - the listview will reveal itself on the bottom and the screen will become split.

The only way I can think of doing this is to generate the UITableView in code, assigning the current ViewController as both delegate and datasource, and animating both the views (calendar and listview) to grow/shrink to split the screen.

I don't want to use StackView because that's IOS-9 and up.

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What should happen to the other views when the list view is hidden?

Comment: When the listview is hidden, the calendar view occupies the entire window. When the listview appears, it shrinks down to half the window.

Comment: Seems easy to do with changing constraints? Have top window and bottom have "equal height" constraint, then break that constraint (and change the other constraints from your code as necessary) to get the thing to move? You could even do an `animate:withDuration` call (much simpler than it sounds) to get the whole thing to animate.

Comment: maybe. I'm just wondering if that's the BEST way to do it.

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell)? Maybe you can look into their code and see how it is done. By the way, are you using a calendar that you built your self? or are you using a ready made one. If is it ready made, then which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're trying to do something like this. Hope it helps:

**Swift 2:**

```
let view2 = UIView()

var screenWidth = CGFloat()
var screenHeight = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenWidth)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.view.addSubview(view1)

    let lbl1 = UILabel()
    lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 50)
    lbl1.text = "This is view 1"
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    lbl1.center = view1.center
    view1.addSubview(lbl1)

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,100)
    btn.center = CGPoint(x: view1.center.x, y: view1.center.y+60)
    btn.setTitle("Show view 2", forState: .Normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "showView2:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view1.addSubview(btn)


    view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight-screenWidth)
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.view.addSubview(view2)

    let lbl2 = UILabel()
    lbl2.frame = CGRectMake(0, (screenHeight-screenWidth)/2-25, screenWidth, 50)
    lbl2.text = "This is view 2"
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    view2.addSubview(lbl2)

}

var c = 0

func showView2(sender : UIButton) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        if (self.c%2 == 0) {
            self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.screenWidth, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight-self.screenWidth)
            sender.setTitle("Hide view 2", forState: .Normal)
        }
        else {
            self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.screenHeight, self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight-self.screenWidth)
            sender.setTitle("Show view 2", forState: .Normal)
        }

        }, completion: { finished in

    })

    c++

}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let view2 = UIView()

var screenWidth = CGFloat()
var screenHeight = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.view.addSubview(view1)

    let lbl1 = UILabel()
    lbl1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 50)
    lbl1.text = "This is view 1"
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    lbl1.center = view1.center
    view1.addSubview(lbl1)

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
    btn.center = CGPoint(x: view1.center.x, y: view1.center.y+60)
    btn.setTitle("Show view 2", for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showView2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view1.addSubview(btn)


    view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight-screenWidth)
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    self.view.addSubview(view2)

    let lbl2 = UILabel()
    lbl2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (screenHeight-screenWidth)/2-25, width: screenWidth, height: 50)
    lbl2.text = "This is view 2"
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    view2.addSubview(lbl2)

}

var c = 0

func showView2(_ sender : UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        if (self.c%2 == 0) {
            self.view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.screenWidth, width: self.screenWidth, height: self.screenHeight-self.screenWidth)
            sender.setTitle("Hide view 2", for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            self.view2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.screenHeight, width: self.screenWidth, height: self.screenHeight-self.screenWidth)
            sender.setTitle("Show view 2", for: .normal)
        }

    }, completion: { finished in

    })

    c += 1

}
```